# cfhttp returns 415 Unsupported Media Type on CF9

Tags: http, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

The following code is working fine on CF10.

```
httpSvc = New http();
httpSvc.setMethod("post"); 
httpSvc.setCharset("utf-8"); 
httpSvc.setUrl(svcLocation);
httpSvc.setClientCert(certLocation);
httpSvc.setClientCertPassword(certPassword);
httpSvc.addParam(type="body", name="body",value=requestParameters);
result = httpSvc.send().getPrefix();
```

The value of requestParameters is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
<S:Body> 
<ns2:processCreditCard xmlns:ns2="urn:com.qvalent.payway.api"> 
<requestParameters>customer.orderNumber=5396&amp;card.CVN=070&amp;order.amount=101&amp;customer.merchant=xxxx&amp;card.expiryMonth=08&amp;card.expiryYear=20&amp;order.ECI=SSL&amp;card.PAN=0000000000000008&amp;card.currency=AUD&amp;customer.username=xxxxxx&amp;order.type=capture&amp;customer.password=xxxxxxx</requestParameters> 
</ns2:processCreditCard> 
</S:Body> 
</S:Envelope>
```

However, when I place it on a CF9 server, the response FileContent is empty and I get the following status code:

```
415 Unsupported Media Type
```

Here is a link displaying the full response: http://www.onoffezy.com/_testing/gateway/

Trawling Google, a 415 status code states that the mime type requested by the client is not available on the server.  However I could not find anywhere that the mime type can be set for request.  Is there a difference int he default mimetype between cf9 and cf10?

I have looked closely at the documentation for both versions, but cannot find a difference that may explain this.

If anyone can shed some light on this and let me know what I need to do differently on CF9 would be hugely appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all that helped.  I found the problem.

```
httpSvc.addParam(type="body", name="body",value=requestParameters);
```

needed to be changed to:

```
httpSvc.addParam(type="xml", name="body",value=requestParameters);
```

It appears that cf9 sends type='body' through as Binary, but cf10 sends it as a string, or works out it is xml and handles it as such.  Once I changed the type to 'xml', cf9 started sending it through as a string of xml, and not binary.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 1):

While I can't say for certain this will solve your problem, have you tried setting the 'Accept' request header to the content type of the response?

For example:

`acceptType = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
httpSvc.addParam(name="Accept", value=acceptType, type="header");`

Comment: Thanks Stinkyfriend.  Tried as you suggested, but same response.  I have added a link to view the full response in the original question.. maybe there is something else there.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d85.html) the `type="body"` *specifies the body of the HTTP request. ColdFusion does not automatically set a content-type header or URL encode the body contents. To specify the content-type, use a separate cfhttpparam tag with type=header.*  So maybe it will help to specify this header for your request.

Something like:

```
httpSvc.addParam(type="header", name="Content-Type", value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

You did not supply an example of your body content.  You may have to play around with the value for your specific content type.  [Here is a list of the available MIME types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME_type).

You have misspelled the word parameters in the variable `requestParamaters` from your example.  What is the value of it?

Comment: Hi Miguel, I think you have me focused on the right area.  When I set the Content-Type, I now get the same error for cf10 as well.  So same error for both cf9 and cf10.  So heading int he right direction.  I am sending SOAP XML, so played around with other values such as application/soap+xml but still getting '415 Unsupported Media Type'.

Comment: Also, I have included the value for requestParamaters in my original question.  Thanks!!